# LINQ-to-XML: Selecting specific node value

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read the below xml using XMLDocument, but I am not getting any success. I want to read all the child nodes
whose parent node have specific key. Like in below case I only want to read all child nodes with parent having attribute "softdrink".
I cannot use the xpath.

```
<root>
  <food>
    <drink key="Softdrink">
      <coke>$12.50</coke>
      <lemonade>$12.80</lemonade>
      <beer>$19.40</beer>
    </drink>
    <drink key="hotdrink">
      <tea>$11.19</tea>
      <soup>$18.22</soup>
    </drink>
  </food>
</root>
```

Comment: You need to escape the XML so we can see it

Comment: Just curious: Is there a specific reason why you cannot use XPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> softDrinks=
    from item in menu.Descendants("Drink")
    where item.Attribute("key") == "SoftDrink" 
    select item;
```

**EDIT** It's been a while since I did Linq To Xml, but I think if you look @ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx#Y400) it will go a long way.